# Custom redirect on custom page for admin user

Tags: forms, redirection

I've created a basic page with url login.

The node id is 129 and I've made a custom `page--node--129.tpl.php` in my theme.
On that file I've put this:

```
<?php print $messages; ?>
<div class="admin-login">
<?php print drupal_render(drupal_get_form('user_login')); ?>
</div>
```

So on this page I'm rendering the user_login form and I'm using it as a page for admin login.
How can I set redirect when admin is logging, lets say to admin/content?

Comment: You can use rules module to redirect user based on role.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've managed to solve this by using Rules module and here's the process, so maybe will help someone.

Create a new rule.

Events: User has logged in.

Condition: User has role

Actions: Page redirect

Answer (score 2):

Implement [`hook_user_login()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!user!user.api.php/function/hook_user_login/7):

```
function MY_MODULE_user_login(&$edit, $account) {
  if(/* CONDITION, e.g.: $account->uid == 1 */) {
    $edit['redirect'] = 'admin/content';
  }
}
```

Comment: I've used a Rules module, but your answer is useful too, so I'm giving you +1. Thanks.